# Why are attributes coming as a string of a ActionController::Parameters object in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I just upgraded to Rails 5.

After submitting a form for `@shift`, I try to call in my controller:

`@position = Position.find params[:shift][:position_id]`

I get a 'no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer' error.

When I check the params:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"shift"=>"#<ActionController::Parameters:0x007fecd4e83208>", "sms"=>"true", "controller"=>"admin/overtime", "action"=>"confirm"} permitted: true>
```

If I call: `params.to_h`, I get:

```
{"shift"=>"#<ActionController::Parameters:0x007fecd4e83208>", "sms"=>"true", "controller"=>"admin/overtime", "action"=>"confirm"}
```

The shift param is `"#<ActionController::Parameters:0x007fecd4e83208>"`...a string!?

If I do:

```
params.require(:shift).permit(:position_id)
```

I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `permit' for "#<ActionController::Parameters:0x007fecd4e83208>":String
```

How can I retrieve the values?

Answer (score 0):

What was happening was that in my `ShiftsController` I was redirecting to the an `OvertimeController` confirm action:

```
admin_overtime_confirm_path(shift: params[:shift], sms: true)
```

Since in Rails 5 ActionController::Parameters no longer inherits from HashWithIndifferentAccess, calling params in an application will now return an object instead of a hash. So it was sending a string version of the ActionController::Parameters object.

To fix it I did:

```
admin_overtime_confirm_path(shift: params[:shift].permit!.to_h, sms: true)
```